# TSQL multi-table join filtered view, trying to return multiple columns based on the filter results (instead of one)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have four tables in a filtered-value schema and I am having trouble figuring out how to extend the existing view query to include an additional column based on the filter results.

One table holds default item records, I call these ItemKeys in the example below. This table also holds a default value and default description for each item. In the example this is the dbo.Defaults table.

The next table is a table to group sets of these items for subsequent filter tables. Called dbo.FilterGroup in the example.

The last two tables are filters that point back to both FilterGroup and Defaults along with their own values and descriptions. These tables only contain records for Items that, when the FilterGroup is used, are joined in to filter in order: Filter2 > Filter1 > Default. As you will see in the example this means if Filter1 has an item record it will overwrite the default, and Filter2 will overwrite Filter1, if present.

## The problem

The current view only seeks to bring back the `Value` portion of the filter data, and I must figure out a way to bring back both the `Value` and `Description` of the resulting filtered Item.

Let me show you the example I have which should show the situation more clearly:

Table and data setup:

```
--dbo.Defaults
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='Defaults') drop table dbo.Defaults; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Defaults (
    ItemKey varchar(128),
    DefaultValue varchar(128),
    DefaultDesc varchar(512),    
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into dbo.Defaults VALUES ('Fruit1','Apple','system default value')
insert into dbo.Defaults VALUES ('Fruit2','Orange','system default value')
insert into dbo.Defaults VALUES ('Fruit3','Pear',NULL)
insert into dbo.Defaults VALUES ('Fruit4','Tomato','system default value')

--dbo.Filter group
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='FilterGroup') drop table dbo.FilterGroup; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.FilterGroup (
    ID integer NOT NULL
        IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_ParamFilterSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF),
    GroupName varchar(128)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into FilterGroup values ('Group1')

--dbo.Filter1
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='Filter1') drop table dbo.Filter1; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Filter1 (
    ItemKey varchar(128), --Defaults.ItemKey
    GroupID int, --FilterGroup.ID
    FilterValue varchar(128),
    FilterDesc varchar(512),     
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into dbo.Filter1 VALUES ('Fruit2',1,'Seedless Orange',NULL)

--dbo.Filter2
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='Filter2') drop table dbo.Filter2; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Filter2 (
    ItemKey varchar(128), --Defaults.ItemKey
    GroupID int, --FilterGroup.ID
    FilterValue varchar(128),
    FilterDesc varchar(512),     
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
insert into dbo.Filter1 VALUES ('Fruit3',1,'Pyrus Pear','filter2 value')
```

My query:

```
SELECT fg.GroupName as [FilterGroup]
    ,d.ItemKey as [ItemKey]
    ,coalesce(f2.FilterValue, f1.FilterValue ,d.DefaultValue) as [Value]
FROM dbo.Defaults d cross join dbo.FilterGroup fg
                    left outer join dbo.Filter1 f1 on f1.ItemKey = d.ItemKey
                                                    and f1.GroupID = fg.ID
                    left outer join dbo.Filter2 f2 on f2.ItemKey = d.ItemKey  
                                                    and f1.GroupID = fg.ID
```

Existing query correctly filters as I described above, bringing back Filter2 values over Filter1 values, Filter1 values over Default values, and Default values if no filters are present on a given item.

What I'm struggling to figure out is how I can include the f1.FilterDesc, f2.FilterDesc or d.DefaultDesc based on which filter is hit in the select coalesce set.  How can perform this join and pull both 'value' and 'desc' columns from the table that emerges from the coalesce?

I thank you very kindly in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Use `CASE` instead of `COALESCE` since your columns are NULLable and that's it. Besides you have a mistake in `f2` join predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method is:

```
SELECT fg.GroupName as [FilterGroup],
       d.ItemKey as [ItemKey],
       coalesce(f2.FilterValue, f1.FilterValue, d.DefaultValue) as [Value],
       (case when f2.FilterValue is not null then 'f2'
             when f1.FilterValue is not null then 'f1'
             else 'default'
        end) as which
FROM dbo.Defaults d cross join
     dbo.FilterGroup fg left outer join
     dbo.Filter1 f1
     on f1.ItemKey = d.ItemKey and f1.GroupID = fg.ID left outer join
     dbo.Filter2 f2
     on f2.ItemKey = d.ItemKey and f1.GroupID = fg.ID;
```

A more clever way puts the logic into the `from`:

```
SELECT fg.GroupName as [FilterGroup],
       d.ItemKey as [ItemKey],
       coalesce(f2.FilterValue, f1.FilterValue, d.DefaultValue) as [Value],
       coalesce(f2.which, f1.which, 'default') as which
FROM dbo.Defaults d cross join
     dbo.FilterGroup fg left outer join
     (SELECT f1.*, 'f1' as which
      FROM dbo.Filter1 f1
     ) f1
     on f1.ItemKey = d.ItemKey and f1.GroupID = fg.ID left outer join
     (SELECT f2.*, 'f2' as which
      FROM dbo.Filter2 f2
     ) f2
     on f2.ItemKey = d.ItemKey and f1.GroupID = fg.ID;
```

Should the last condition be `f1.GroupId = fg.ID` or `f2.GroupID = fg.ID`?

Comment: I just came back here to post the solution I came up with which was the select CASE method

I will consider the other approach you suggest. 
Yes, there were some typos in the example - that's one of them sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's answer ranking approach:

```
;with allFilters as (
  select f.ItemKey,
         f.GroupID,
         f.FilterValue,
         f.FilterDesc ,
         2 rank --<<<
  from dbo.Filter1 f

  union all

  select f.ItemKey,
         f.GroupID,
         f.FilterValue,
         f.FilterDesc ,
         1 rank --<<<
  from dbo.Filter2 f

  union all

  select f.ItemKey,
         NULL GroupID,
         f.DefaultValue,
         f.DefaultDesc ,
         3 rank --<<<
  from dbo.Defaults f
),
filtersRanked as
(
  select f.ItemKey,
         f.GroupID,
         f.FilterValue,
         f.FilterDesc ,
         -- now computing most preferred per ItemKey
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f.ItemKey ORDER BY f.rank ASC) rn
  from allFilters f
)

SELECT fg.GroupName as [FilterGroup],
    f.ItemKey as [ItemKey],
    f.FilterValue,
    f.FilterDesc
FROM dbo.FilterGroup fg
left join filtersRanked f
  on (f.GroupID = fg.ID or f.GroupID is NULL) -- NULL support for defaults
    and f.rn = 1 --<<< "top 1" by rank
```

Easy to manipulate which source has higher priority.

Output:

```
FilterGroup ItemKey FilterValue FilterDesc
Group1  Fruit1  Apple           system default value
Group1  Fruit2  Seedless Orange (null)
Group1  Fruit3  Pyrus Pear      filter2 value
Group1  Fruit4  Tomato          system default value
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1511d/1

Also you've got some typos:

- 'Pyrus Pear' I guess is supposed to be inserted into `Filter2`
- `f1.GroupID` is mentioned in join predicate for `Filter2` instead of `f2.GroupID`

Comment: Yes sorry for the rushed example, surprised there were not more errors! Thank you for the suggestions and your time - cheers !